# Sending email using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, email

I am trying to send email using ASP.NET through Gmail server. This is my code, can you help me how to resolve the timeout issue.

```
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com"); 

            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High;
            mail.From = new MailAddress("FromEmail@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add("ToEmail@gmail.com");
            mail.Subject = "Fees Reminder";                
            mail.Body = "Please, Student ID: " + username + " pay your fees " + sqlFeesValue + ".";
            mail.Body += " <html>";
            mail.Body += "<body>";
            mail.Body += "<table>";
            mail.Body += "<tr>";
            mail.Body += "<td>User Name : </td><td>" + username + "</td>";
            mail.Body += "</tr>";
            mail.Body += "<tr>";
            mail.Body += "<td>Fees : </td><td> " + sqlFeesValue.ToString() +"</td>";
            mail.Body += "</tr>";
            mail.Body += "</table>";
            mail.Body += "</body>";
            mail.Body += "</html>";

            smtp.Port = 465;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "passwd");
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;                
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            lblMessage.Visible = true;
            lblMessage.Text = error.Message;
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail

Comment: I think you need to create body in a string variable assign into body, Then try. Or may be you are using wrong port number

Comment: Try port 587. Are you sure you don't get the gmail timeout because of the new security settings in gmail?

Comment: As I know SSL uses 465. What are the new security setting: Alexander.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: When debugging I can see full message in Send(mail). The mail variable can show me a complete packet.

Comment: I changed code a little bit and it shows this message:  "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required."

Comment: Login to your Gmail account and see the recent activity. From there you can select "Yes it was me" and then re-run the code and `server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required` error should go away

Comment: Thanks Izzy! Now it works. I had got message from Google but didn't pay my heed to it. But thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different port number. 
Gmail will accept port 25 or 587 when sending mail but times out using port 465.

Also make sure you have UseDefaultCredentials = False also.

Comment: I also tried using these settings but not worked for me.

Comment: Can you try using,smtp.EnableSsl = false;

Comment: This link can be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail @Patrick has added the same link as comment. :)